# HTML5 WebSQL and AppCache on Blackberry Playbook

Tags: html, web-sql, html5-appcache, blackberry-playbook

I have a web client that makes use of HTML5, webSQL and appcache.  Apparently, it won't work on Blackberry Playbook.  It works fine in an android device.  I thought playbook supports webSQL, then why I'm not able to create a websql db?  I've also tried visiting sites with webSQL demo on the playbook but it won't work either.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using so far? I'm pretty sure I've used it successfully before.  Try visiting http://www.html5test.com/ that detects PlayBook support for WebSQL, and http://www.html5demos.com/ that has a live DB test you can try yourself.

Comment: Clear the browser data on the playbook and then try again and see what happens.

Comment: @scunlife thanks, the html5test.com will be very useful since I'm trying it out on different devices.  Yeah, it's weird, I mean I've tried it out on blackberry ripple emulator and it works fine.  I've tried visiting demos from html5rocks.com and it won't work either.

Comment: Then it looks WebSQL is not supported (or not properly supported) on the Playbook.  I thought it was as well but I've never used one.  We've run into some issues with iPad 2 not properly maintaining local browser Databases and clearing all of the browser data seems to reset it, thought that might help the playbook. I'd get off of the WebSQL train ASAP if I were you though.  It's an enormous headache.

Comment: But it works on ripple blackberry emulator.  If I'm not going to use webSQL, I'll end up using IndexedDB which is just the same, not all browsers and devices supports it